# The .NET Core feature AllowedHosts is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, web-hosting

I have a micro service built on .net core v3 and hosted in the `ATIKA` domain which is on a virtual machine of Azure. I want to access hosted API from the `IVKLA` domain only and other than this domain should get 400 status code.

So in allow host is taken care in the `appsettings` file

```
"AllowedHosts": "IVKLA.com"
```

Even with this setting, however, I am getting 400 status code from any Postman request made from `IVKLA` domain computers.

I have tried other forum posts but still did not got any proper answer.

> The information below was last updated on October 21, 2022.

As suggested, I have tried using URL ReWrite in IIS server. I Was able to block the IP and getting 403 forbidden status.
But when I have try to white list an IP I am getting
"500URL Rewrite Module Error"

This is the URL rewrite from web.config

```
<rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="Authorized Admin IPs">
                <add key="1.2.3.4" value="1" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Authorized admin" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{Authorized Admin IPs:{REMOTE_ADDR}}" pattern="1" />
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="*.*.*.*" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_X_AUTHORIZED_ADMIN" value="yes" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="un Authorized users" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_AUTHORIZED_ADMIN}" pattern="yes" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="forbidden" statusDescription="forbidden" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: You probably misunderstood how it is supposed to be used, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/host-filtering?view=aspnetcore-6.0 In your case, the reasonable value to set is "ATIKA.com", but clearly in this way `AllowedHosts` won't filter incoming requests for you. URL Rewriting Middleware is the one you should utilize.

Comment: I tried today with CORS but still I am able to access it from anywhere from postman.

Comment: Like I said, `AllowedHosts` is the wrong way to go. Have you configured URL Rewriting Middleware? You need the IP range from domain administrators of `IVKLA` and then enforce source IP check in URL Rewriting Middleware to block unwanted requests.

Comment: You are right I have tried using URL ReWrite in IIS server. Was able to block the ip and getting 402 forbidden status. But when i try to white list an IP I am getting 500URL Rewrite Module Error

Comment: @LexLi I have updated my details in the main description with URL Rewrite config